# Makefile Macro to ignore all files named test

Tags: makefile, macros

I'm trying to create a makefile for this project of mine, but I'm quite new to the concept. I have a makefile for each project, and a overarching make file in my main directory which I can call that communicates with all the other makefiles.

I have a few files I have named "test" to help me debug my project. By default, I want to have these test files included in my build, but with macro (ex: make TEST_FILES=false), I want to omit the files from the build.

Is there a convenient way to omit all files named "test"?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The `Makefile` per source file sounds... unusual. Most of the `make` documentation assumes a `Makefile` per _project_; i.e., the topmost directory of the software being built.

Comment: oh my, that's a very important typo on my part. it is indeed a makefile per project, not source. Editted!

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
# Makefile

ifeq ($(TEST_FILES),false)
  SOURCES := $(filter-out test%, $(wildcard *.txt))
else
  SOURCES := $(wildcard *.txt)
endif

all:
    @echo $(SOURCES)
```

which does this:

```
$ LC_ALL=C ls -nlah && \
> make all && \
> TEST_FILES=false make all

total 72K
drwx------   2 10335 11111 4.0K May 26 15:36 .
drwxrwxrwt 585     0     0  60K May 26 15:31 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 10335 11111  157 May 26 15:36 Makefile
-rw-r--r--   1 10335 11111    0 May 26 14:57 bar.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 10335 11111    0 May 26 14:57 foo.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 10335 11111    0 May 26 14:57 qux.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 10335 11111    0 May 26 15:30 test_bar.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 10335 11111    0 May 26 15:30 test_foo.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 10335 11111    0 May 26 15:27 test_qux.txt

bar.txt foo.txt qux.txt test_bar.txt test_foo.txt test_qux.txt

bar.txt foo.txt qux.txt
```

References:

- https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Text-Functions
- https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Wildcard-Function
- https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Conditional-Syntax